# find data from the mongodb push in array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, multithreading, loops

I am trying to push data `arrayList` from the collections document. As seen in code bellow and console.log  and res.js(ArrayList) return [] Null. Please help me, anyone.

```
 var  UserList=[];

 gamebit.find({"game_room":req.body.game_room,"game_status":"1"},(err,result)=>{
    if(err)
    {
      res.json(err);
    }

    else{
     for(i=0;i<result.length;i++){
       tblregistration.findOne({"mobile":result[i].mobile},(errer,user)=>{
          if(user)
            {
            if(user.usertype=="D")
                 {

                UserList.push(user);
                 }

                 else if(user.usertype=="N")
                 {
                  if (user.companyId != "outsite")
                  {
                  tblregistration.findOne({"referral_code":user.referral_codeby},(err,use)=>{
                       if(use)
                       {
                        UserList.push(use);


                       }
                    else
                    {
                      console.log(err);
                    }


                  });
                   }

                 }
                 else{
                  tblregistration.findOne({"companyId":user.companyId},(err,u)=>{
                   distpersent+=distpersent+u.dpercentise;

                   UserList.push(u);
                });
                }

              }
            });
          }


        }
    });
console.log(UserList);

  res.json(UserList);
```

> out put
>
> null
>
> []

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the below code.

```
var UserList = [];
gamebit.find({ "game_room": req.body.game_room, "game_status": "1" }).exec((err, result) => {
    if (err) { res.json(err); } else {
        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            tblregistration.find({ "mobile": result[i].mobile }).exec((errer, user) => {
                if (user) {
                    if (user.usertype == "D") {

                        UserList.push(user);
                    }

                    else if (user.usertype == "N") {
                        if (user.companyId != "outsite") {
                            tblregistration.find({ "referral_code": user.referral_codeby }).exec((err, use) => {
                                if (use) {
                                    UserList.push(use);
                                } else {
                                    console.log(err);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        tblregistration.find({ "companyId": user.companyId }).exec((err, u) => {
                            distpersent += distpersent + u.dpercentise;
                            UserList.push(u);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }


    }
});
console.log(UserList);

res.json(UserList);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203567/discussion-on-answer-by-foram-trada-find-data-from-the-mongodb-push-in-array).